# Javascript location.reload() wih JSP short url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to invoke a javascript call which is `location.reload();` when a button is pressed. This function works as expected, now the problem is that I am using a JSP page and the entire url is not found in the location so what is happening is `location.reload();` is sending me back to my homepage.

For example

```
alert(location); // ouput: www.server.com/site/servlet/page
```

If I press f5 on my browser it will reload the page as I expect it to

I would like to reload the same page

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I am simply calling

function reload(){
 location.reload(false);
}

Comment: Not clear ! do you want to reload the same page?

Comment: if you console.log `window.location.href`, and go to that url, does it work?

Comment: no because widow.location.href still points to the page. I believe the application is stripping everything from the location after 'servlet/page'. But why does manually clicking the refresh page work how I would expect location.refresh() to

Comment: Shadow, yes I want to reload the SAME page:)

Comment: What do you mean by "still points to the page"? What are you expecting it to point to? How is the reload button behavior different from what you expect `location.reload()` to do, or pasting `window.location.href` into the location bar?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding some proprietary javascript calls within this BI application to refresh the page. Thanks for the help